# Report Generation, Taking hours

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, report

I am generating a xml file for success or failure from two database tables, but it is taking 24 hours to generate it.

I have 2 select queries, one for success and one for failure.. I am hitting database for 1 million times for each records.

I am using JDBC and Java IO for writing in file.

Please suggest some good ideas

Comment: There is no way to answer this without seeing the queries.

Comment: @hogan You don't have a crystal ball?

Comment: no report generation tools.

Comment: @Paharichora - no crystal ball

Comment: @nlk - actually I do, it is almost certain this person's problem is one of two things - sub-queries instead of joins or multiple selects on the client side when one would do.

Comment: It would be nice if you could've posted the sql and the code so we could give better advice than just generic tips.

Comment: I posted this question when I was in a meeting..so did not write it in detail, but unfortunately it had been interpreted wrongly...I know it is very basic requirement in projects where you have large volume of transactions and you have to send some kind of short status report back.. that's the reason of using simple code (JDBC, Java IO) to generate this kind of short report, I never expect this kind of reputation I will get from ppl. God bless all....

Answer (score 1):

The only possible answer to this that you clearly need to optimize your SQL and / or your application design so that you don't "hit" the database as much.

With so little detail, it is not possible to say how you should optimize, but maybe you should look at doing a JOIN ...

Comment: I had mentioned in the question itself that I am using a simple select query,for example: select id from table where loanNo=?, we were missing indexes for this table. definitely I am not using batch here because the system which I have does not allow...there are some limitations... its long story....

Comment: Notwithstanding ... you have not provided enough detail for us to help you.

Comment: @StephenC Crystal ball.